# How to load text from file with just one single button?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to code a message encrypt/decrypt page using character subtitution.
I managed to save key to a file and I want to load it back.
I managed to load key successful with this:

```
    <script>
    function loadkey () {
    var keyToLoad = document.getElementById("keyToLoad").files[0];
    var keyReader = new FileReader();
    keyReader.onload = function(keyLoadEvent)
    {
        var keyFromFileLoaded = keyLoadEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("key").value = keyFromFileLoaded;
    };
    keyReader.readAsText(keyToLoad, "utf-8");
}
</script>

<h3>Put your key here</h3>
<textarea id="key" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="genKey()">Generate  key</button>
<button onclick="savekey()">Save key</button>
<input type="file" id="keyToLoad">
<button onclick="loadkey()">Load key</button>
```

But it loodk really stupid with select file button and load key button separately.
So I hide input button and trigger it from clicking Load key button:

```
<script>
    function handleChooseKey()
{
    document.getElementById("keyToLoad").click();
}

function loadkey () {
    var keyToLoad = document.getElementById("keyToLoad").files[0];
    var keyReader = new FileReader();
    keyReader.onload = function(keyLoadEvent)
    {
        var keyFromFileLoaded = keyLoadEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("key").value = keyFromFileLoaded;
    };
    keyReader.readAsText(keyToLoad, "utf-8");
}
</script>

<h3>Put your key here</h3>
<textarea id="key" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="genKey()">Generate  key</button>
<button onclick="savekey()">Save key</button>
<input type="file" id="keyToLoad" style="display:none;">
<button onclick="handleChooseKey();loadkey();">Load key</button>
```

My problem is it cant make the loadkey() function work right after the key file is loaded, so the key wont be loaded until the next click. Please help me. Thank you :)

Comment: I guess you cannot simulate events on `file` input. I would make the file input transparent and place another button on top of that. So, user will think that he is clicking on something else. Now, from `change` event of the file input I would call `loadKey()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function handleChooseKey()
{
    document.getElementById("keyToLoad").click();
    document.getElementById("keyToLoad").onchange = function(e) { loadkey() };
}

function loadkey () {
    var keyToLoad = document.getElementById("keyToLoad").files[0];
    var keyReader = new FileReader();
    keyReader.onload = function(keyLoadEvent)
    {
        var keyFromFileLoaded = keyLoadEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("key").value = keyFromFileLoaded;
    };
    keyReader.readAsText(keyToLoad, "utf-8");
}
</script>

<h3>Put your key here</h3>
<textarea id="key" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="genKey()">Generate  key</button>
<button onclick="savekey()">Save key</button>
<input type="file" id="keyToLoad" style="display:none;">
<button onclick="handleChooseKey();">Load key</button>
```